# Group by statement dynamically using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I try to figure out how to group by dynamically using linq. I found a lot of solutions, but not the right one for me, because most solutions are using different column names, but not changing numbers of columns. I have to use a variable number of columns and variable columns. I get the column names in a List from the settings the user has made.

An example:
The user wants to group the first time like this.

`var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month, x.Day });`

But maybe the next day he wants to group just like this.

`var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Hour, x.Minute, x.Second, x.Year});`

or just this.

`var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Hour});`

how to do that?

---

EDIT:
I think I found a solution. If my List conatins the "year" I set the bool to true. And so on.

```cs
bool includeYear = true;
bool includeMonth = true;
bool includeDay = false;
bool includeHour = true;
bool includeSecond = false;
var grouping = aList.GroupBy(g => new { 
                             Year = includeYear ? g.Year :(int?)null,
                             Month = includeMonth ? g.Month: null,
                             Day = includeDay ? g.Day :(int?)null,
                             Hour = includeHour ? g.Hour : null,
                             Second= includeSecond ? g.Second : null});
```

Now it is possible to turn the columns on and off by using the booleans. I'm still testing but I dont know what about the sequence of columns, makes it a difference?

Comment: How does the user specify the criteria?

Comment: I've not used it myself, but Dynamic-Linq supports  https://dynamic-linq.net/ supports something along these lines. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ppOOeo is an example of usage.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The user can select one or multiple columns from a grid he wants to group by

Comment: Is the set of columns fixed?

Comment: Are all the values numeric? i.e. could you calculate a single value from them and group by that. Runtime creation of anonymous types is much harder.

Comment: @AluanHaddad for the time being yes, but I don't know, maybe in the future I have to add columns

Comment: @IanMercer was just an example, the values could be everything

Comment: If you want simple just get the list of columns to filter and find all their reflection properties into a `List<PropertyInfo>` and then simply makeup a key made of their combined values with arbitrary splitter like `var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => string.Join("~", properties.Select(prop=> prop.Invoke(x).ToString())));`

Comment: If the columns are known  at compile time. You could associate each column with a function that projects a row to the column's value. Something like `IDictionary<string, Func<RowType, object>> = new () { ["Column1"] = x => x.Something, ["Column2"] = x => x.SomethingElse };`. Then you could compose them into an aggregate value equitable type with elementwise equality.

Comment: I edited my post. Please have a look, maybe you can help anyways

Comment: Since `GroupBy` for anonymous objects is field by field equality, order of columns shouldn't matter. BTW, why the cast to `(int?)` on only some of the fields?

Comment: @NetMage the fields are examples, a year can be an integer, a month can be a string and so on. Its just to show how to make the fields nullable and to make this way work